# Can I register or renew a domain name without going through a commercial site?

Tags: domains

If I want to register or renew www.therandomcatsite.com, I know for sure that I can pay GoDaddy about $12 to do so, and GoDaddy notes that the ICANN fee is $0.18. Is it possible to personally file a registration or renewal with ICANN (or whatever central organization handles registrations) and only pay the $0.18 fee?

Comment: No, AFAIK, you can only register a domain name through an approved registrar. But currently GoDaddy's having a special, [$0.99 for one year](http://www.godaddy.com/domains/search-dus.aspx?gclid=CPSOu4_U8rQCFcaDQgodywMAaw&isc=gofa2005ab&ef_id=UPmkJwAAQH8d@nBh:20130118193836:s). I have no affiliation; that link comes from an ad atop a Google search for "domain". There's even a couple ads for $0.50 & $0.75.

Comment: @AKTed: They're probably still trying to make up for the mass exodus of domain owners that resulted from their support of SOPA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: no, you can't.

The long answer is: yes, you can. But in order to do so you'll need to be accredited by ICANN. [See here.](http://www.icann.org/en/resources/registrars/accreditation)

Comment: Even then you really can't. As I understand it, ICANN collects a fee per domain, but it's the TLD registry that collects most of profits from registrars. That's why it's worthwhile for businesses to buy control of a TLD if they have the money to do so. For example, Versign owns the .com and .net TLDs (among others), and they charge a registry fee of $7.85 and $5.11 per year for each.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté Is it possible to register a .com domain directly from Verisign?

Comment: @Cory: No, only registrars perform retail sales to end users.

Answer (score 1):

ICANN doesn't provide domain registration services. They oversee the functioning of DNS and various other high-level things, including accrediting registrars. ([FAQ here](http://www.icann.org/en/about/learning/faqs); especially see "What is ICANN?") Providing registation would probably be a a conflict of interest, actually.